# Getting CheckBox value on Databound then setting the GridView row color if checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My application is ASP.Net, C#, Webforms.
I have a Gridview - named gvCustNames
I have the gridview set to run code on `OnDataBound="setRowColor"`

Here is my C# syntax:

```
protected void setRowColor(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustNames.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[3].FindControl("cbViewCutsomer") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
            }
        }
    }
```

The application compiled ok with no errors but when I try view it in the browser I get this error:

> A method or delegate `sbmanager.cm.setRowColor(object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)' parameters do not match delegate`System.EventHandler(object, System.EventArgs)' parameters

Which means I am not using the correct event handler.
What handler should I be using?

Comment: according to the error you should use ```protected void setRowColor(object sender, EventArgs e)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handling OnDataBound, which is called once whole GridView completed data binding process. It is indeed expecting EventArgs argument. That's why the error. Now you have two options:

1. Simple. Replace GridViewRowEventArgs with EventArgs. Make sure to also change `e.Row` with `row`.
2. Probably clearer. You are running through all rows anyway, so why not handle OnRowDataBound instead? Args stay the same, and no need for a loop:

   ```
   protected void setRowColor(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       CheckBox chkRow = (e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("cbViewCutsomer") as CheckBox);
       if (chkRow != null && chkRow.Checked)
       {
           e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
       }
   }
   ```